# Doctrine Trait override OneToMany relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have `trait` which looks like this

```
trait CommentableTrait
{
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappeBy="to_override")
     *
     */
    protected $comments;
}
```

In the `Comment.php` I have `ManyToOne` relation

```
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="comments")
     */
    protected $article;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="comments")
     */
    protected $page;

     /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="comments")
     */
    protected $question;

}
```

I want to use this trait in my entities `Article.php`, `Page.php`, `Quesion.php` like this:

```
class Article
{
    use CommentableTrait;
}
```

I need to override `mappedBy` in `CommenatableTrait`.

I've tried the solution from [Doctrine - Override Field Association Mappings In Subclasses](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html)

It works with `OneToOne` and `ManyToMany` relations but I couldn't find a working example for bi-directional `OneToMany - ManyToOne` relations. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `trait` within a class and override relation there. For example:

```
class Article
{
    use CommentableTrait;

    /**
     * @See CommentableTrait
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappeBy="article")
     *
     */
     $comments      
}
```